# Including multiple steps as external file in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm trying to split my pipeline to multiple files,
So one stage has multiple stages inside it, I want to move it to a different file inside `vars` directory in jenkins-shared-library I'm importing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('utils-library') _

def podLabel = "whatever"
def pod = "some yaml..."

pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label podLabel
            defaultContainer 'jnlp'
            yaml pod
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Nightly Tests') {           
            library externalNightlyStages
        }
        stage('Regular run') {
            steps {
                echo "bla!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `utils-library` I have a file named `vars/externalNightlyStages.groovy` and its content:

```
def call() {
    stages {
        stage("Spin up fresh EMR") {
            steps {
                echo "Spinning up an EMR cluster"
            }
        }
        stage("Run stage on EMR") {
            steps {
                echo "Run stage on EMR"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So theoretically, calling this library inside the pipeline should just import the stages and run as if it was all on one file.
However, this does not work.

I tried calling the library from different places, surround with `script` block, surround with `steps` block.
Nothing did the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please show how you have tried invoking the method from the library in your pipeline?

Comment: @MattSchuchard take a look inside the stage Nightly Tests: `library externalNightlyStages`